# How to show that $\sum_{0}^{M} \sin(\sqrt{n^{2}+1}x) $ is bounded $\forall x \in (0,\pi)$ for any constant $M$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tried to estimate it like $Const\cdot \sum_{0}^{M} \sin(nx)$ ($M$ is arbitrary). And the last one is obviously bounded. But didn't find any constant. Any hints ?

Comment: I'm confused, a simple lower and upper bound is $-M$ and $M$, I must be misunderstanding something. Can you elaborate?

Comment: May be you could state in the question title that the same bound is to hold for all $M$?

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=0}^M\sin nx$ blows up at $x=\pi/(2M)$ by the same calculation I gave in my answer, so you did something wrong there. May be the question is not quite what you really wanted to ask?

Comment: After all, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^M\sin nx=\frac{\cos(x/2)-\cos([M+\frac12]x)}{2\sin(x/2)},$$
so that simpler sum is large when the denominator $\sin(x/2)$ is tiny, but the two cosines don't cancel. OTOH here the denominator is bounded away from zero in an interval $(\epsilon,\pi)$, so for this simpler variant we do get a bound independent of $M$ in a slightly shorter interval. I suspect that this is what you really want for your sum also.

Comment: (con'd) That is, are you really asking for a bound $N(\epsilon),\epsilon>0,$ such that your sum is bounded from above by $N(\epsilon)$ for all $M$ and for all $x\in(\epsilon,\pi)$? The bound $N(\epsilon)$ here should not depend on $M$, but it may (and will) depend on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum of that sum of functions in the interval $x\in(0,\pi)$ grows linearly with $M$, so a bound independent of $M$ cannot exist.

The problem appears at the low end of that interval. Let $x=\pi/(2M)$. Then $\sqrt{n^2+1}x$ always belongs to a suitable interval like $I=[0,9/5]$ (we may need to exclude a few small values of $M$). In the interval $I$ we have the lower bound $\sin x>x/2$. Therefore

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^M\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}x)&\ge \sum_{n=0}^M\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}x}2\\
&\ge\sum_{n=0}^M\frac{nx}2\\
&=\frac{M(M+1)x}4=\frac{\pi (M+1)}8.
\end{aligned}
$$

This kills all hope for a bound that holds for all $M$ and all $x\in(0,\pi)$.

On the other hand plotting a few such sums suggests that the problem is **only** at the low end. Here is what the plot looks like with $M=50$,

[image]

and here's how it changes when $M=100$.

[image]

A surprisingly similar overall shape if you ask me! <strike>I guess the fact that the periods of the summands are linearly independent forces significant cancellation to take place when $x$ is large enough!</strike> After viewing a few more such plots it would not necessarily surprise me if to each interval $x\in(\epsilon,\pi)$, $\epsilon>0$, there were a bound that would not depend on $M$ (but by the above example it would necessarily depend on $\epsilon$).

Comment: The sums do seem to blow up again when $x\to2\pi$. That shouldn't be too hard to explain using the fact that $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is close to being an integer for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-1 \leq \sin(y) \leq 1$ for every $y,$ we have that $-M \leq \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^M \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}x) \leq M.$

Comment: I didn't mentioned that $M$ is arbitrary and bound is common for all $M$.